# Modificar parte del texto que hay dentro de un select HTML

Tags: html

El problema que tengo es que estoy haciendo un formulario y hay un select el cual es para seleccionar un plan y quisiera que a la derecha del todo se mostrara el precio del plan para que quede mas organizado. He intentado con span modificandolo desde el css y otras cosas con javascript pero se me ha hecho imposible. Alguna ayuda o idea no me vendría mal

```html
<select name="tipoPlan" id="tipoPlan" class="form-select">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona el tipo de plan</option>
  <option value="individual">Individual CLINIGOLD 50$</option>
  <option value="individual">Individual ESMERALDA 125$</option>
  <option value="familiar">Familiar CLINISEGURO 500$</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Quieres que fuera del select en un span se muestre el precio??? Por otro lado, estás repitiendo los `value`,  me parece que en tu caso deberían ser únicos

Comment: Nono, no quiero que se vuelva a repetir el precio, lo que quiero es que el precio que hay dentro del option se alinee a la derecha del option, no que se repita o se coloque de nuevo

Comment: Truco "feo" pero funcional: si agregás como CSS `direction: rtl;` (_rigth to left_) a `option`, ¿luce como esperás?

Answer (score 0):

Con un addEventListener puedes registrar el evento "change", con este puedes obtener el valor de tu select y dependiendo del valor puedes mostrarlo dentro de un div o cualquier otro elemento que quieras.

```
    <div style="display: flex;">
    <select name="tipoPlan" id="tipoPlan" class="form-select">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona el tipo de plan</option>
        <option value="Individual-CLINIGOLD">Individual CLINIGOLD 50$</option>
        <option value="Individual-ESMERALDA">Individual ESMERALDA 125$</option>
        <option value="Familiar-CLINISEGURO">Familiar CLINISEGURO 500$</option>
    </select>
    <div id="price"></div>

</div>


  <script>
    const priceDiv=document.getElementById("price")
    document.getElementById('tipoPlan').addEventListener("change",(event)=>{
        if(event.target.value=="Individual-CLINIGOLD"){
            console.log(50)
            priceDiv.innerText="50";
        }
        if(event.target.value=="Individual-ESMERALDA"){
            console.log(125)
            priceDiv.innerText="125";
        }
        if(event.target.value=="Familiar-CLINISEGURO"){
            console.log(500)
            priceDiv.innerText="500";
        }
    })
  </script>
```

También puedes poner el precio dentro del value de cada option

```
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <select name="tipoPlan" id="tipoPlan" class="form-select">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona el tipo de plan</option>
        <option value="50">Individual CLINIGOLD 50$</option>
        <option value="125">Individual ESMERALDA 125$</option>
        <option value="500">Familiar CLINISEGURO 500$</option>
      </select>
      <div id="price"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("tipoPlan").addEventListener("change",e=>{
        console.log(e.target.value)
        document.getElementById("price").innerText=e.target.value;
    })
  </script>
```